# How does controllers find models Schema file in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have below structure and I think this is not correct

### models/db.js

```
var mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' );
var mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost/loc8r';
var mongoDB = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);
require('./user');
```

### models/user.js

```
var mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' );
var Schema =  mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username : { type: String; required: true},
    createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});
mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

### controllers/user.js

```
var mongoose  = require( 'mongoose' );
var user = mongoose.model('User');
```

My questions are ( co related )

- How does *controllers/users.js* pages get in touch with *models/users.js*
- What if there is more than one file in models folder, say *model/college.js* then Do we add more `require()` lines in db.js?
- somewhere I see that `module.exports` are written at the end of the model schema files, does that is right way or above one is correct?
- Why do we keep adding `require mongoose` continuously in each page?  coming from PHP background , I think that once we add require it will be added in child pages when we include the file. is it not so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the more elegant way which re utilize `mongoose` object across other model files. I hope this will help newbie which are also facing issue to understand the concept.

use `module.exports` in main db file which is added in `require()` in *app.js*

#### models/db.js

```
let mongoose  = require('mongoose');
let mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost/loc8r';    
module.exports = mongoose.connect(mongoURI,options);    
let conn = mongoose.connection;
```

***Note:*** I have removed `require(..other model file ..)` from bottom of **db.js**

---

### models/user.js

```
let mongoose  = require( './db' );
let Schema =  mongoose.Schema;
let userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String; required: true},
    createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

***Note:*** add `require('./db')` in place of `mongoose` in each other model file and export the schema using `module.exports` in bottom

---

### controllers/user.js

```
let User = require('../models/user');

module.exports.userSignup = function(req,res,next) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var user = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password,
            email: req.body.email
        });
        user.save( (err, user) => {
            if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            return res.status(200).json(user);
        });
    } 
};
```

***Note:*** add model files with help of `require(...)` , so that it will get schema detail and use that variable to save/update new data

feel free to correct if I am wrong or doing the lengthy way.